# Break a bash loop when [return] key is hit

Tags: bash, loops, break

Is it possible, in bash, to get out of a loop which doesn't wait for the user input when the [Return] key is hit?

Here is the kind of loop I mean. The key is [q]. I would like it to be [Return].

```
#!/bin/bash

stty -echo -icanon time 0 min 0 # Don't wait when read the input

i=1

while [ 1 ]; do

   echo -ne "$i\r"

   ((i+=1))

   read key

   if [ "$key" == "q" ]; then break; fi # If [q] is hit, get out of the loop

done

stty sane # Come back to the classic behavior

exit 0
```

Comment: In `vim` for example you can do `<Ctrl+v>` and then hit `<return>` and you should see a `^M` character. That's the one you want to compare against.

Comment: Hello, actually @Brice is right when he says that $key is void when the user enters only [Return] during a 'read' command. But the problem is that because of the third line of my script (stty -echo...) even if the user doesn't enter anything, $key is void at the 'if' position.
I am afraid there is no solution to this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that the user pressed exactly <kbd>Return</kbd> (aka. <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and not something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, simply check that the exit code is zero (since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will result in a non-zero exit code) and that the key is empty:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ -z "$key" ]
then
    break
fi
```

Comment: You did it ! :D :D :D
Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

In case the user types `<return>` without typing anything else, `$key` will be an empty string.

Just check for the empty string too:

```
if [ -z "$key" ]; then break; fi
```

As per [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), `-z` tells checks for a *zero length* string.

Comment: `-z` doesn't tell `if` to check for a zero length string. It's the `test` command that checks it and returns true/false which `if` then acts upon. Small but important differences.

Comment: Hi brice, The problem is that because of the first commented line, if the user doesn't hit any key, $key is a void string. So there is no difference between when it hits [Return] or not.

Comment: @brice Doesn't matter if you use `[[` or `[` (or even `test` or `grep`), `if` just checks whether the following command returns zero or not.